# How to identify whether setting is scoped user or application using code?

Tags: c#

How can find settingproperty scope(whether user or application)

```
foreach (SettingsProperty setting in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
{
     //Find the scope of the setting
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`SettingsProperty.IsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsproperty.isreadonly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value should indicate if it can be changed. If it can not, it's an application setting.

Comment: IsReadOnly Property is false for both user scope and application scope